# Can "above mentioned" be a noun?

Tags: phrases, nouns

> The above mentioned regulations do not apply to the conditions defined here.

Is it possible to use the phrase *above mentioned* as a noun with the definite article "the" in English?

> The above mentioned does not apply to the conditions defined here.

Is it possible to use the verb in the plural after the *above mentioned*?

Comment: As a (compound) participle it works fine as an adjective, and adjectives, notably including such participles, routinely function as nouns. I think the usual compound, however, is *the aforementioned.*

Comment: Yes. It might not be the best way to convey your meaning in terms of people understanding it correcly though. Especially depending on just how much has been mentioned above.

Comment: Thanks for the aforementioned. I'll keep it  in mind. @Brian Donovan

Comment: In my opinion, the example you give is incorrect. I would have written "The above-mentioned regulations ...". I've frequently been thrown in my understanding of a phrase by the absence of the hyphen in the adjective. One egregious example I read in an airline magazine talked of "mail delivering postmen" which had me briefly wondering why postmen would be delivered in the mail.

Comment: No, "above mentioned" is a modifier, but "the above mentioned" is a perfectly good noun phrase.  It has no noun, which is understood from context to be something like "item(s)".

Answer (score 1):

"How should I edit your above-mentioned(1) comments without offending you?" wrote Jim to his sister, Jimina.

"Please don't edit anything, Jim", she retorted, "Just leave the abovementioned(2) alone, as usual.  I'm far too agitated to hear your snarky criticism."

Jim bugged her, "The abovementioned(3) isn't really worth talking about, though."

She responded, "I'll have you know that my abovementioneds(4) do get read by and are respected by tens of people across this country, therefore they are worth talking about."

1. adjective
2. noun
3. singular or collective noun and verb conjugation
4. plural noun (not collective) and verb conjugation

The highest probability is to find it in its adjectival form, hyphenated as in, above-mentioned.